# Binding - callback is called twice

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, callback

I've a simple control with dependency property like this

```
public class StatusProgress : Control
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(StatusProgress),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => (d as StatusProgress).TextUpdated(e.OldValue as string)));

    private void TextUpdated(string text)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
```

then I have view model

```
public class ViewModelPageAnalyse : ViewModelPageBase
{

    private string _progressText;
    public string ProgressText
    {
        get { return _progressText; }
        set
        {
            _progressText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // base class INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is a user control (displayed in window with `ContentControl`). User control is bound to view model with data template (maybe this is important)

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelPageAnalyse}">
    <local:UserControlAnalyse/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this is the control in user control

```
<local:StatusProgress Text="{Binding ProgressText}"/>
```

Now the interesting part. When `ProgressText` in view model is set/changed, property changed callback is called twice. I see twice `"test"` in the debugger output window.

More interesting: when view is changed, for some reason callback is again called with `e.NewValue = null`, while there is nothing directly sets `ProgressText` to `null`.

I tried already to check if value is changed in the `ProgressText` setter before rising event, tried to set binding mode one-way, problem still - callback is called twice with same value, call stack looks same, but there are really a lot of calls within wpf to be really sure.

While double-shot is not a real issue, it bother me. Callback with `null` value is what my real problem (I think they are related). Anyone knows what is wrong?

---

Found a reason of the first problem: it was other control with `Content`. During transition it created a new `Model` (because `Content` is `ViewModel`) instead of reassigning existing user control. Totally my fault. Second problem still and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19131159/1997232) question (with workaround which is not suiting me).

Need help with

> PropertyChanged callback is called with default value when ContentControl ViewModel is changed.

Which means `null` for `Text` in my case. Anyone? I couldn't figure out why is it called. My guess it is called by `DataTemplate` manager, if I can say so.

Answer (score -2):

try to change this line:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(StatusProgress),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => (d as StatusProgress).TextUpdated(e.OldValue as string)));
```

with this:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(StatusProgress)
    , new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Comment: But.. but.. I need callback (to do some logic and animations). Do you possibly knows other solution to get to know when dependency property value is changed?

Comment: i think that writing your logic when ProgressText (before calling OnPropertyChanged();) changes is easier than writing it when DependencyProperty changes

Comment: `ProgressText` belongs to view model (another class), that's not possible. I should have been tagged the question with `MVVM`, sorry.