# Alternative to re-rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have control with following desing:

- there is dependency property `Text`;
- this text is set to inner `TextBlock` and then control is auto-sized (to fit).
- when this property is changed callback is executed;
- in callback I need both: current control appearance and one after changing text (for animations).

What I have now is this:

```
// ... do something
textBlock.Text = Text;
ContentText.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, (Action)delegate() { });
// ... do something
```

Unfortunately, said line (which force render) will throw `InvalidOperationException`

> Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended

I have opened [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24759864/1997232) regarding that case (for some reasons callback is called with `null` when changing `ContentControl` content with my control inside).

In my opinion solution could be also alternative way to re-render content. Or perhaps some checks to avoid that exception.

Is there any other way to re-draw (re-render) content or is there any way to check, when using dispatcher is prohibited (because it's suspended)?

I could only think of adding timer, to delay execution, so that content will be re-rendered. This would split logic in 2 peaces: in callback and in timer. And doesn't really looks nice.

Comment: Why don't you just call `Measure` on the TextBlock and then get its `DesiredSize`?

Comment: You call InvalidateVisual method which should re-render the control. You can read more about this here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Krishna, `InvalidateVisual` doesn't work. Perhaps it works asynchronously (as many things in wpf). If there was an event `OnRendered`, then I could use it, but this again will split my logic into 2 peaces. Still seems much better than using the timer.

Comment: @Clements, awesome idea and it works! When I say *content* I mean layout in fact (appearance is rendered during animation by itself as I see it, but it is important to measure accurately start/end position and that's why I tried to re-render control to get proper size, etc.). Thanks!

Comment: @Sinatr If you are setting the text for the TextBlock in the code behind, then can you listen to the textchanged event of the textblock and call the InvalidateVisual over there? Then I would guess the operation would be complete and then you can run your animation/style

Comment: @Krishna, I am in callback, `RenderedSize` before and after setting `Text` is the same, disregards of calling `InvalidateVisual()`, which seems to me as if rendering does not occurs immediately, but queued instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clemens, idea to use `Measure` seems to be a really nice working solution. Moreover, this principal allows to overcome many other problems (which never disappears since the time I touch `wpf` for the first time), I already have 2 less...

In short:

- if unsure in rendered size, call `Measure()` with parameter `RenderSize` of parent container;
- then use `DesiredSize` instead of `RenderSize` (`ActualWidth`/`ActualHeight`).

Works like a charm. <strike>Best part is to call that on parent control, which will recalculate everything, taking in account its children (like in my case, I call measure for my control and its measuring updated `TextBlock.Text`).</strike> Has to be called for children individually!